# How to mock the entire AbortController class using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm using **Jest** and **AbortController** at the same time.
**AbortController** has a **signal** property which returns an **AbortSignal**, which itself has a **reason** property.
However, the **reason** property isn't supported in node yet, thus all of my test are failing due to this.

I've tried

`jest.spyOn(AbortController.prototype, 'AbortController').mockImplementation(...)`

to mock the constructor but I still got the following error :

> "Argument of type '"AbortController"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"abort"'."

I cannot use jest.mock() because AbortController isn't imported.

I don't really know what to do from now on, has anyone ever tried this ?

Comment: The [`reason` property](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/globals.html#abortsignalreason) was added in 2022-02-08's [Node LTS 16.14.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V16.md#2022-02-08-version-16140-gallium-lts-danielleadams), are you able to update to that / newer?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding these lines to my jest configuration, inside the package.json :

```
"jest": {
        [...yourConfig],
        "globals": {
            "ts-jest": {
                "isolatedModules": true
            }
        },
}
```

The tests weren't compiling because of a typing problem. Jest was using **@types/node**. This solved the problem.